# Retrieving session Id in linux kernel (Kernel Space)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, sessionid

I want to retrieve the sessionid of the current process in linux kernel (Kernel Space). I saw `task_struct` has a field `sessionid` but it is defined only when the macro `CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL` is ON. So i tried to build the kernel with this macro ON but still i was not getting the result. Also I tried getting its value from function with `CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL` on `audit_get_sessionid(current)` but was getting either -1 or junk value ( different from  `getsid(0)` method in user space).

I am struck at this point. Any suggestion would be of great help.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the `getsid` syscall at here: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=kernel/sys.c#l1106

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(getsid, pid_t, pid)
{
     struct task_struct *p;
     struct pid *sid;
     int retval;

     rcu_read_lock();
     if (!pid)
             sid = task_session(current);
     else {
     ...
```

Which suggest you can use the kernel function task_session() to get the session id.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kuba for the prompt reply. I tried using what you mentioned but i was getting different results for getsid(0) in user space and task_session(current) in kernel space.

The values are :15422 (with getsid(0) )
               :3473445976 ( with task_session(current))

Comment: I just figured it out :  

      pid_vnr(task_session(current));

would return us the current session's id.

Thanks to Kuba...

Comment: @sebe It scares me that you're writing kernel code, and didn't notice that `sid` in the example code was a *pointer*.

Answer (score 0):

pid_vnr(task_session(current)); would do what u want!!

Comment: This appears to have been posted hours after the asker reported it as the solution in a comment.