# How can I retrieve a task's sessionid in an eBPF program?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I want to retrieve the sessionid from a task struct in an eBPF program. I have the following code in my eBPF program:

```
struct task_struct *task;
u32 sessionid;    

task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
sessionid = task->sessionid;
```

This runs, but the sessionid always ends up being -1. I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422806/retrieving-session-id-in-linux-kernel-kernel-space#answer-10422912) answer that I can use `task_session` to retrieve it, but I get an error about invalid memory access. I believe I need to use `bpf_probe_read` to move the `task_struct` that `task` points to onto the stack, but I can't get it to work. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly why this is happening without seeing your code. Note that eBPF cannot call arbitrary kernel function.

Comment: Yeah I think I could have been more clear about how I was building the program/how I was injecting it - I managed to get the sessionid in a different way so I gave an answer myself. I'm now trying to do this :p https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447855/how-can-i-track-interactive-shell-sessions-that-dont-allocate-a-tty-using-ebpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit more digging through the `task_struct` struct I realised you could do this:

```
struct task_struct *task;
struct pid_link pid_link;
struct pid pid;
unsigned int sessionid;

task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();

bpf_probe_read(&pid_link, sizeof(pid_link), (void *)&task->group_leader->pids[PIDTYPE_SID]);    
bpf_probe_read(&pid, sizeof(pid), (void *)pid_link.pid);

sessionid = pid.numbers[0].nr;
```